# Do multiple @Before methods work in Controller inheritance?

Tags: java, controller, playframework

I'm trying something similar to this, and only one of the @Before methods gets called:

```
public abstract class ControllerBase extends Controller {
  @Before
  static void foo() {
    // this actually gets called
  }
}

public class ConcreteController extends ControllerBase {
  @Before
  static void bar() {
    // This DOES NOT get called
  }

  public static void index() {
    render();
  }
}
```

Is this a bug, feature, or something I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to do something weird. And I think your example doesn't match your question.  Did you mean to implement ConcreteController on ControllerBase? Rather than both of them extending on Controller?

The @before tag is a concrete class tag.  Only the one in the concrete class will get executed.

You can @override the original function, but I don't think that's what you were looking for.

The best way to get what you want is to remove @before from the abstract and from the concrete function call the implemented function you want to run.

```
public abstract class ControllerBase extends Controller {
  static void foo() {
    // this actually gets called
  }
}

public static class ConcreteController extends Controller {
  @Before
  static void bar() {
    foo();
    // This DOES NOT get called
  }

  public static void index() {
    render();
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I fixed my example - I really think all @Before methods in the inheritance chain should be called (like the semantics of jUnit's @Before). Opened an issue https://play.lighthouseapp.com/projects/57987-play-framework/tickets/1266-call-all-before-methods-in-a-controller-inheritance-chain

Comment: Actually, I found the problem - multiple @Before attributes do work (including those on abstract classes). See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Play! will call all the methods in the inheritance hiererchy annotated with `@Before`.

The problem I ran into was that the `@Before` I was using was actually `org.junit.Before` instead of `play.mvc.Before` !

Comment: Yes exactly, you can use @Before where ever you like, static methods are inherited in Java.